# calculate percentage increase/decrease between 2 numbers with many decimals in bash

Tags: bash, math, percentage, bc

I need to calculate the percentage increase/decrease between 2 numbers in a bash script, and I need at  2 decimals after . The numbers will have many decimals (eg.  684.0800000, 683.7550000).
I`ve seen bc can do that, but i cannot get it to work.kind regards

Comment: How did you use `bc`?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo 684.0800000 683.7550000 | awk '{printf "%.2f%\n", 100*($2/$1-1)}'

-0.05%
```

that is `0.05%` decrease from first to second, which is `-0.0475` rounded to two decimal points.

Answer (score 1):

Use the bc `scale` variable to determine the precision

```
x=684.0800000
y=683.7550000
echo "scale=2; 100 * ($y - $x) / $x" | bc
```

```
-.04
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `bc` and formating output with `printf`:

```
$ a=684.0800000
$ b=683.7550000
$ printf '%.2f\n' $(echo "100*$b/$a-100" | bc -l)
-0.05
```

With more digestable values:

```
$ a=5
$ b=2
$ printf '%.2f\n' $(echo "100*$b/$a-100" | bc -l)
-60.00
```